# Unable to separate file names with file contents in Python socket programming

Tags: python, regex, file, sockets

I'm trying to send data from the client's side to the server's side using TCP socket programming.

What I did is I read in the file names in the client's directory and then send the file name to the server's side by sending `clientSocket.send("FILE "+fileToTransfer + "\n")`. Then on the server's side, I use regex to get the file name out.

However, the client will always send the "FILE fileName.txt" and the file's contents together. So I suppose at the server's side, I will have to use regex to separate the file name with the file's contents.

So what I did at the server's side is to use `getFileName = re.match(r'FILE (.*)(\n)(.*)',data)` to get the file name and its contents separately. Unfortunately, `(.*)` does not include line breaks.

In that case, how do I separate the file contents with the file name? Is there a way to get the client's side to send the file name first then wait for server's side to get the file name before the file contents can be sent over? Or is there a regex which I can use so that I can separate the file name and the file contents?

Comment: You can send the file name and its size as a header and then file content. The server side will read the header, extract the size and then read that size amount of data.

Comment: How do I send the file name as a header then file content as normal data?

Comment: see my answer, too long to explain in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the file size along with the filename. This allows the server side to know how many bytes it should read. And in this case you don't need to read the entire file content into memory, you can read it chunk-by-chunk until the file size is exhausted (zero-ed out) and write chunks to disk. Something like this:

```
## client side
# get file size here, for example:
# filesize = os.path.getfilesize(filepath)
sock.sendall("FILE %s %d\n" % (filename, filesize))
sock.sendall(fd.read())


...
## server side
# error handling is left out
header = ""
while True:
    d = sock.recv(1)
    if d == '\n':
        break
    header += d

filesize = int(header.split()[-1])
# or search for the last space in header
# and get a substring of header as filename
filename = "".join(header.split()[1:-1])
data = ""
while filesize > 0:
    chunk = sock.recv(1024) # or any amount of data
    filesize -= chunk
    data += chunk
```

Or you can give your regex up and just find the first `\n`:

```
## client side
sock.sendall("FILE %s\n")
sock.sendall(fd.read())

...
## server side
# data = read data here
newline = data.find('\n')
assert newline != -1 # some error handling here
header = data[newline]
filename = header[len("FILE "):]
content = data[newline+1:]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am quite confused with some parts of the code. For the first example, what do you mean by "filesize = int(header.split()[-1])" and "filename = "".join(header.split()[1:-1])"? In addition, how am I going to get multiple files? at the client side, should I send another header message (just before the header of each files)? I also realised that if I send multiple files, on the last data chunk from the first file, the header message may be combined with the last data chunk from the first file and sent to the server. In that case, how do I handle such cases?

Comment: Hi! I managed to send multiple files and avoided the problem with first file content combined with the header of the second file by recv(1) each time. However, I realised that I always cannot send .xls, .php, .doc files. I always get the following error: "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'server_side/test.xls'" although I have already open the file for writing. I have updated my code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to fix the regex, change the line to:

```
getFileName = re.match(r'FILE (.*?)(\n)(.*)', data, re.DOTALL)
```

The `DOTALL` flag makes the `.` math newlines as well. The extra `?` I added makes the `*` multiplier non-greedy, i.e., it'll stop at the first newline it sees (I assume newlines cannot be a part of the file name).

What you should probably do is send the file name as part of a header or something.

Comment: r'FILE (.*)(\n)([.\n]*)' doesn't seems to work. How do I use re.DOTALL?

Comment: @cdarke Python re also replaces `/n` with the newline character

Comment: How do I send the filename as part of a header?